# C# DataMember Serializer Ordering Opposite of Expected

Tags: c#, serialization, jsonserializer, datamember, datacontractjsonserializer

According to this article, I'd expect to see the fields in my base class at the top of the list of fields when serializing to JSON.  However, I'm seeing the fields at the bottom of the list.  The ordering is correct within the actual class itself, but not among the hierarchy.

What's happening is it's ordering properly with the class, it it's doing the exact reverse of what I'd expect.  I'd expect the base classes to have their fields serialized first.  I don't want to use the Order=X attribute because there are too many fields in my objects.

**This is the exact opposite behavior as described here:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813(v=vs.110).aspx

```
[DataContract]
public class MyBase {
  [DataMember]
  public long Id { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyChild : MyBase { 
  [DataMember]
  public string Field1 { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Field2 { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Field3 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MySecondChild : MyChild { 
  [DataMember]
  public string SecondField { get; set; }
}
```

***When serializing an instance of MySecondChild...***

**Expected**

```
{ 
    "Id": 1,        
    "Field1": "f1",
    "Field2": "f2",
    "Field3": "f3",
    "SecondField": "s1"
}
```

**Actual**

```
{  
    "SecondField": "s1",      
    "Field1": "f1",
    "Field2": "f2",
    "Field3": "f3",
    "Id": 1
}
```

Comment: I *thought* this was because of the missing `[KnownType]`, but actually I think could be as simple as: what you are reading about `DataMember` only applies to `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: How can I tell if I'm using the DataContractSerializer vs something else? Definitely seems strange since I'm explicitly extending the base classes.

Comment: well, how are you currently serializing them? By what mechanism are you getting from an object to json? Hint: it certainly isn't `DataContractSerializer` because that ***isn't a JSON serializer***

Comment: I'm using the ASP.NET Web API built in JSON serializer.  I removed the XML formatter from the global configuration so that the content would always be serialized as JSON.  I'm not quite sure how to tell what implementation I'm using though.  Any suggestsions? (I agree with you then it must not be the DataContractSerializer, since I'm specifically going to JSON)

Comment: depending on the MVC version, that defaults to `JavaScriptSerializer` or JSON.NET; I've checked, and `JavaScriptSerializer` doesn't seem to obey the `Order` much...

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: http://pastebin.com/PqBEHf6g

```
{"Id":1,"Field1":"f1","Field2":"f2","Field3":"f3","SecondField":"s1"}
```

Comment: AFAIK, MVC doesn't use `DataContractJsonSerializer` as the default

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I think perhaps the serializer being used by ASP.NET Web Api isn't the same serializer? How can I tell here?

Comment: I don't know, read the docs, sorry :). Maybe Newtonsoft.Json? If you observe a different behavior, then you must not be using the DataContract stuff, so the MSDN docs don't apply to you, and also you shouldn't use the [Data*] attributes.

Comment: I think it's using Newtonsoft.Json by default? According to this anyway... http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization -- It worked this way, but it added a _type attribute, and required me to use [KnownType] which was awkward as well.