# Why would a WCF DataContract not serialize members in alphabetical order?

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I have several `DataContract`s that looks similar to this (shortened for brevity):

```
[DataContract(Name = "ItemDTO", Namespace = "http://foo.com/")]
public class ItemDTO : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }
}
```

I hadn't taken notice of the serialized messages before but after a recent change, two things were done: I added a new property, called `ReturnCode`, and ran [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/)'s "Reorganize", which alphabetized the properties.

It now looked something like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "ItemDTO", Namespace = "http://foo.com/")]
public class ItemDTO : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int ReturnCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

According to [Microsoft's page on Data Contract Member Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813(v=vs.110).aspx) I realized `ReturnCode` would break the contract since the serializer would insert it before `Value`, so I added an `Order` attribute value, assuming the original order was alphabetic, yielding:

```
[DataContract(Name = "ItemDTO", Namespace = "http://foo.com/")]
public class ItemDTO : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public int ReturnCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This however threw an exception that the deserialized members were out of order. I rolled back to a prior changeset, before all the changes, and sure enough the original order of the members was not alphabetic in the SOAP request (viewed through [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)), but following the original order expressed in the code, ie: `Name`, `Value`, `Id`.

I'm currently in the process of adding `Order` values to all my old DTO types to sequence them according to their prior, pre-alphabetizing of the properties, arrangement. What I'd like to know is *why* the coded order instead of alphabetized order was being used by the serializer? [Microsoft's rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813(v=vs.110).aspx) say:

> Next in order are the current type’s data members that do not have the
>   Order property of the DataMemberAttribute attribute set, **in
>   alphabetical order**.

**Update:**

After I added the `Order` values to sequence the properties in their original order, I again ran [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and it's still using the order the items are literally coded in. In other words, for some reason, my WCF service is completely ignoring any serialization sequencing logic and just sequencing the properties by the order they appear in the .cs file. In fact, the only way I was able to get it to serialize properly was to physically rearrange the properties in each type to their original order. That worked, but it's not preferred.

**Update 2 - Solution:**

Following Dracor's advice, I added `[XmlElement(Order = 1)]` attributes and an `XmlRootAttribute` to my DTOs. The SOAP serialization *DID* end up following the ordering assigned by these attributes. I hadn't considered it but my service does use [Castle DynamicProxy](http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.DynamicProxy.ashx) and so I'm guessing it's changing the serializer from `DataContractSerializer` to `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: What serializer are you using? See this question for some information regarding the effect of the serializer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004946/c-sharp-datamember-serializer-ordering-opposite-of-expected

Comment: It's a SOAP message generated by a WCF service, so it should be the XML `DataContractSerializer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply use XmlSerializer to Serialize/Deserialize your XML? It's way more forgiving than DataContractSerializer, and works most of the time.

Comment: The problem is I only control the serialization side; customers already have their own SOAP clients with their own deserializers. I can change my client but it won't solve the problem.

Comment: But then again why would that be a problem? If you use it to serialize your data you can assign both the namespace (through the constructor's second parameter) as well as the order things get serialized in (i.e. `[XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]` - note: you could try using this attribute with your current classes and serializer as well. I wouldn't be surprised if it worked.)